# Get users information when creating a customer

Tags: hook, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to create a Prestashop Module which when a user is created, I can get all his information automatically using `ActionCustomerAccountAdd`, this event return (`$params`), but I don't know the structure of the object params for getting the data needed

I tried to create `hookActionCustomerAccountAdd` which get params, I was able to get just the email of the customer `$params['newCustomer']->email`, but I can't get the first name and last name and the password

```
// Will be executed each times actionCustomerAccountAdd is triggered
public function hookActionCustomerAccountAdd($params)
{
  // $params is an array set by PrestaShop which contains the 
  // hook data (here, the customer details

  $this->CustomerAdd($params['newCustomer']->email);

  /*   $json_output = json_decode($params,true); 
        var_dump($json_output) ;
        echo "Works";
  */
}

public function CustomerAdd($mail){
   $myObj->userx->UserID = 0;
   $myObj->userx->Username = "NameUser";
   $myObj->userx->Password ="Password";
   $myObj->userx->Fname ="Fname";
   $myObj->userx->Lname= "Lname";
   $myObj->userx->Mail= $mail;
   $myObj->username= "evdokimosk";
   $myObj->password="123425";
}
```

I expect to get all data I need like first name, last name but I don't know what is inside the `$params`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$params['newCustomer'] is the object of the client, so you can retrieve customer information:  :

```
$firstname = $params['newCustomer']->firstname;
$lastname = $params['newCustomer']->lastname;
....
```

Regards

Comment: but in the case $params['newCustomer']->password it return null ! @ethercreation